# What's the difference between the World Wide Web and the Internet?

Tags: networking

I've seen a few online resources saying that WWW != The Internet. Can someone explain like they would to a complete noob?

Found that WWW consists of all web resourcces and identifies them using URL's. What is the internet then? Is it not the same? Or is the WWW a subset of the internet?
Pls help me understand

Comment: _"January 1, 1983 is considered the official birthday of the Internet."_  and _"Tim Berners-Lee, a British scientist, invented the World Wide Web (WWW) in 1989"_ was the two first hits I got when searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internet is a global system of interconnected computer networks, upon which WWW is only one of the usable protocols, being used for multimedia (text+audio+graphic) information, which makes WWW part of the Internet.

In example, FTP which is a file transfer protocol, is part of the internet functionality, but not a part of WWW (but can be used as an ftp link as part of web page).

This is the reason why every web site address starts with http(s):// - you are telling the browser that you are using the http(s) protocol which is the protocol used by the World Wide Web.

Hope it was clear...

Answer (score 0):

The internet is a global network of interconnected computer networks, while the World Wide Web (also known as the Web) is a collection of documents and other resources, linked by hyperlinks and URLs, that are accessed via the internet. The internet is the infrastructure that allows for the communication and transfer of data, while the Web is a way to access and share that data.

To use the internet, you need a device such as a computer, smartphone, or tablet, and a way to connect to the internet, such as through a wireless network or an internet service provider (ISP). Once connected to the internet, you can use a web browser to access the Web and view websites, as well as send and receive email, participate in online discussions, and more.